# How to combine multiple Observables together in Angular 2

Tags: angular, observable, subject, behaviorsubject

So I've just started programming with Angular 2 and just got started on learning about subscribe, Subject and BehaviorSubject. Currently I have multiple subscriptions to obtain values stored in my service and emitted to a component. My application works and all but I know it is very inefficient. That it has gotten out of hand in my component:

```
this.threatService.minLimitChange$.subscribe( min => { this.min = min; this.getSession();});
this.threatService.maxLimitChange$.subscribe( max => { this.max = max; this.getSession();});
```

(and like 5 other more that obtains a single value and calls function getSession() each time)

In my threat.service:

```
private minLimitChangeSource = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.min);
private maxLimitChangeSource = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.max);
minLimitChange$ = this.minLimitChangeSource.asObservable();
maxLimitChange$ = this.maxLimitChangeSource.asObservable();
```

So I've tried:

```
this.threatService.minLimitChange$.concat(this.threatService.maxLimitChange$).subscribe( res => console.log(res));
```

Which my aim was just to test what res was because I wasn't sure how to access the two values... but I'm getting this in my console. ;/

```
TypeError: this.threatService.minLimitChange$.merge is not a function. (In 'this.threatService.minLimitChange$.concat(this.threatService.maxLimitChange$)', 'this.threatService.minLimitChange$.concat' is undefined)
```

Ultimately, I'd like to get all values that getSession() needs from my service and run that function **once**. I would really appreciate any help or explanation on how to use concat, merge or forkJoin to combine my subscriptions please. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Observable.combineLatest` to combine 2 observable streams into one:

```
combineObs = obs1.combineLatest(obs2, 
  (val1, val2) => { 
    return {val1: val1, val2: val2};
  });
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mmCzEmdKexpaWNM53me9?p=preview

Comment: Ah I see! That seems close to what I want however, I don't use the values via the {{ }} method in the html. My application is actually a chart generator that shows data points according to the slider in UI component. So the data flows: Slider in **UI Component** sends max and min values > **Service** stores and emits to subscriber > **Chart Component** runs a function with those values. 

So if I were to place the combineLatest in my chart component how would I assign it locally in the component's max and min values?

Comment: Hey check the attached plnkr link. Basically the idea is to achieve your task in 2 steps: 1. Combine two streams into one, the third stream will emit a new value every time either of the source stream has a new value; 2. Listen to the combined stream and populate your local data based on the combined data. I've demonstrated both in the plnkr.

Comment: Thank you! It works nows and cut down on a lot of redundant code.

Was lost because I didn't have a class like Settings and I had a separate service and a main component so the functions and variables aren't together like your plunker. But I understand now (: Thank you again!